# How to define this constructor in an appropriate way?

Tags: kotlin

I have the following two classes:

```kotlin
data class Problem(
  val id: String,
  var units: Long,
  var items: Map<String, ItemToPack>
)
```

```kotlin
data class Solution(
  val id: String,
  var items: Map<String, PackedItem>,
  var totalWeight: Long?
)
```

This way the an instance of Problem and an instance of Solution are completely independent.

I want to prevent this behavior in the following way: Given a `Problem` instance, I want to be able to create a `Solution` instance of the same `id`. The keys of `items` in solution needs to be the same as the keys of `items` in problem.

How to make such a constructor?

Comment: So the behavior that you want is that when you create a `Problem` instance, it automatically generates a `Solution` instance with the same `id` and common `items`, and the creation of a `Solution` instance does not generate a new `Problem`, correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Solution` depends on `Problem` you can introduce a `solver` method as a static builder pattern, but with Kotlin flavour.

```kotlin
data class Problem(
        val id: String,
        var units: Long,
        var items: Map<String, *>
)
```

```kotlin
// Use private constructor to protect instantiation
data class Solution private constructor(
        val id: String,
        var items: Map<String, *>,
        var totalWeight: Long?
) {
    companion object {
        // Use Problem extension to provide a scoped static builder
        // Use exactly the same id as in Problem instance you're going to solve
        fun Problem.solve(): Solution {
            return Solution(id, ...)
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    Problem("42", 42L, emptyMap()).solve()
}
```

Comment: What justifies the use of companion objects here ?

Comment: Companion object is a Kotlin way to handle static functions and variables, to implement a static builder pattern you need a static function.

Comment: Ok thanks, is there a way to use the same keys inside the map of items in Solution instance as the ones in Problem instance? I tried the following but obiviously, it doesn't work 

```fun Problem.solve():Solution{
      return Solution(id, items.map { item -> mapOf(item.key to PackedItem(item.key))})
    }```

Comment: In other words, I don't want to have an empy map in solution's items

Comment: Just access `items` and do what you want to do with them. Replace `*` in Map signatures with a proper type if you didn't.

Comment: Use `items.mapValues { (key, value) -> value.convertToOtherTypeOfValue() }`.